# 3D transformations on Android View / ViewGroup

Tags: android, 3d

I am trying to make a 3D-looking scrollable list, with elements stacking in a row moving forward and backwards, and all that needs to be 3D-looking (back elements faded out and scaled down, etc). Problem is that the front element, when moving out of the view (more to the front, that is) needs to rotate on X-axis and sort of "fall down", as if it was falling from an end of a conveyor belt.

I have searched far and wide for an elegant solution that does not involve developing a real 3D environment or applying whole code libraries, but could not find anything of the sort. I am really a noob at developing for Android, so I guess I might have overlooked something.

The only solution that came close to it was using a 0-duration animation that applied rotation transformation via Camera class onto View's canvas, but that wasn't a good enough 'cause the View's boundaries were clipping the rotated content, and let's face it - that's a crooked way to apply something as trivial as rotation.

Is there really no simple way to rotate Views? I mean, iOS has it, Flash has it - even CSS3 gives a way to do it without breaking a sweat.

My target is API 10 (2.3.3) and up.